# Error mounting in fstab Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, mount

'm working on a bash class project which needs me to create 2 partitions in Ubuntu and make them be automatically mounted each time the systems boots with fstab.

I got the following file which creates (I think correctly) the 2 partitions needed and adds them to the fstab file.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SVN Partition
(echo n; echo p; echo ; echo ; echo +20G; echo w;) | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

#WEB Partition
(echo n; echo p; echo ; echo ; echo +5G; echo w;) | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

sudo su -c "echo '/dev/sdb1        /svn  ext4    rw,user,auto,utf8      0       0' >> /etc/fstab"
sudo su -c "echo '/dev/sdb2        /web  ext4    rw,user,auto,exec,utf8 0       0' >> /etc/fstab"
When I reboot the system an error appears telling me the automatic mounting for /web and /svn failed.
```

Does anyone have a clue on what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you stop half way through, do /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 exist? do the folders /svn and /web already exist? mount won't create a mount point if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the partitions with a filesystem using mkfs.

Also, forget the su's and sudo's - just toss an if/then block in at the top to check if the script is being run with a user account that has the appropriate permissions (or as sudo).